# Custom OrderByComparator day of DateTime

Tags: service, liferay, dynamicquery

I need to order my DynamicQuery by the number of day on a DateTimeColumn (Contact_ table by the way)

the default orderByComparator bring:

```
1969/04/02
1970/04/01
1970/04/01
1970/04/11
```

but I need

```
1970/04/01
1970/04/01
1969/04/02
1970/04/11
```

I tried overriding OrderByComparator and then using him on my dynamicQuery() method, but doesn't work

Tried to implement OrderByComparatorFactory myself but my compare method isn't called

I thing I can use a custom query, but there's no other way to do it?

by the way, I'am using a search container

Answer (score 0):

DynamicQuery does not use compare method from an OrderByComparator method. DynamicQuery adds only the fields and asc/desc from the OrderByComparator.

See the Liferay code here:
BasePersistentImpl:

```
public List findWithDynamicQuery(
        DynamicQuery dynamicQuery, int start, int end,
        OrderByComparator orderByComparator)
    throws SystemException {

    OrderFactoryUtil.addOrderByComparator(dynamicQuery, orderByComparator);

    return findWithDynamicQuery(dynamicQuery, start, end);
}
```

OrderFactoryUtil:

```
public static void addOrderByComparator(
    DynamicQuery dynamicQuery, OrderByComparator obc) {

    if (obc == null) {
        return;
    }

    String[] orderByFields = obc.getOrderByFields();

    for (String orderByField : orderByFields) {
        if (obc.isAscending(orderByField)) {
            dynamicQuery.addOrder(asc(orderByField));
        }
        else {
            dynamicQuery.addOrder(desc(orderByField));
        }
    }
}
```

You may sort the result list by your comparator, as I did it in this example:

[github](https://github.com/peterborkuti/portlet-tutorial/tree/038-dynamicquerywithcomparator)